# How do I find the time complexity of a nested for loop

Tags: time-complexity

```
Code(int n)
{
int s=0; int i=0; int j=0;
for(i<n;i++)
    {
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
        s+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

How do i write out the time complexity of functions like this one?

```
Code(int i) -> T(n)
{
int s=0; int i=0; int j=0; -> O(1)
    for(i<n;i++) -> n
    {
        for(j=i;j<n;j++) -> (n-1)*?
    {
    s+=1; -> (n-1)*?
    }}}
```

So maybe T(n)=O(n)+2*O(n-1)+O(1)+?

How am i supposed to write the complexity of  for(j=i;j<n;j++) ? Thanks!

Comment: Big-O notation is only concerned with the _shape_ of the growth curve. Something like `O(n)+2*O(n-1)+O(1)` is actually just `O(n)`. Your loops here are O(n*n), even though technically they are executing less than n-squared times, more like (n*(n+1)/2)

Comment: Right.  The point of the O notation is that if you double `n`, the runtime goes up by a factor of 4.  It doesn't produce the exact runtime, just the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop goes from 0 to n-1, while the inner loop goes from i to n-1, which means it executes n-i iterations (given by (n-1)-i+1=n-i).

In order to compute the complexity we have to sum the iterations of the inner loop for each iteration of the outer loop. In other words, if `**I**` is the number of iterations, we have:

```
**I** = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1
```

This quantity can be computed through Gauss' formula:

```
**I** = [n*(n+1)]/2 = (n^2+n)/2 = O(n^2).
```

Note that `O(n^2)` is just an asymptotic (i.e. it represent the behavior of the function as n goes to infinity) upper-bound for the complexity of the algorithm and it does not indicate the exact number of iterations.